# How to update toValue for a spring animation in React Native (Animated API)?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

I'd like to be able to change the `toValue` of an animation responding to props update. The [official docs for React Native `Animated` API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#spring) state that the spring method

> animates a value according to an analytical spring model based on damped harmonic oscillation. Tracks velocity state to create fluid motions **as the toValue updates**, and can be chained together.

However, I haven't found *anywhere* how we can update `toValue`. Basically, my component looks like this:

```
const ProgressBar = ({ loadPercentage }) => {
    const loadAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    useEffect(() => {
     animation.current = spring(loadAnim, {
       toValue: loadPercentage,
     }).start(); 
    }, [loadAnim, loadPercentage]);       

    ....
}
```

This doesn't work for all cases. In particular, if `loadPercentage` changes too often, the component takes up a huge amount of resources. This kinda makes sense, since I'm creating a new animation for each update. Instead, I'd like to simply modify `toValue` without starting a new animation or anything like that.

This seems pretty basic, but after 4 hours of trying stuff/googling, I give up. -.-

Just in case, I also tried using `react-native-reanimated`, but no luck there either.

Comment: I share your confusion :) As nobody has turned up to answer this, I guess we'll remain in the dark.